# WordPress editor issues

Tags: wp-editor

I was not able to submit any post through WP Editor and users are also not able to submit a new post.There was a problem with the editor and I reinstalled WordPress, it solves for me but does not for other users.

Also getting this error. WP site [LINK](https://www.qautimes.com)
[image]

Comment: Can you ask your users try login to your site in private browsing. May be cache cause the problem.

Comment: Yes, it works.But how can I clear cache for all my users? I installed WP Super Cache but it thinks it is not working.

Comment: But why I am getting error can you also solve out this?

Comment: It's not the cache of WordPress itself, it's browser cache. You can write a guide or give your user some link help them to clear their cache.

Comment: Is your problem fully solved? If yes, I can write an answer to make this question solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think clearing cache will solve the problem for your users, because it's not the server cache but their browsers cache. Ask them to use `Ctrl + F5` and it will help to access non-cached version of your website.